# Send a select field for response on Paypal

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

Is it possible to send a set of values to Paypal that are then parsed as a select box on the Paypal checkout screen?  To give this context consider the following.  If a website has a donate button which sends users to Paypal to make a donation is it feasible to ask the user at Paypal which "fund" they wish to donate to?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. You'll need to collect this data prior to sending the customer to PayPal.